# Django data migration raising a Type Error

Tags: python, django, typeerror, database-migration

I've got two relevant models; `Item` and `Category`, and I'm trying to write a data migration to place existing items into categories. The migration looks like this so far:

```
def categorise(apps, schema_editor):
    Category = apps.get_model("orders", "Category")
    Item = apps.get_model("orders", "Item")
    some_category = Category.objects.create(name="Category name")
    some_category.items.add(Item.objects.get(name="Item name"))


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('orders', '0005_populate'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(categorise)
    ]
```

And the (relevant parts of the) models look like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

When I perform the migration listed above, though, I run into a type error on the last line of the `categorise` function. It tells me `TypeError: 'Item' instance expected, got <Item: Item object>`. That's odd, since they seem like the same type. I took care to import the `Item` model via apps rather than through a regular `import` in order to make sure it would be the same historical model definition that created the items currently in the database.

What could be the reason?

**EDIT:** Here are the relevant bits from the previous migrations. I now realise some of these originate from before I updated to Django 1.8. Is that relevant?

**EDIT 2:** As it turns out, running `python manage.py migrate` twice in direct succession does fix the issue. What does that mean?

**Update:** this turned out to be a bug in 1.8, but will be fixed when the patch for [ticket 24573](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24573) is merged.

0001:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Item',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, verbose_name='ID', auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200))
            ],
            options={
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
    ]
```

0002:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('orders', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('items', models.ManyToManyField(to='orders.Item'))
            ],
            options={
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
    ]
```

0003:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('orders', '0002_category'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='item',
            name='discounts',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, to='orders.Discount'),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

0005:

```
def populate(apps, schema_editor):
    Item = apps.get_model("orders", "Item")

    def add_item(name):
        item = Item.objects.create(name=name)
        # ..

    add_item("Item name", 160)
    # .. etc

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('orders', '0004_auto_20150328_0929'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate)
    ]
```

Comment: I can confirm that this problem is still there in django 2.2.15 as of Feb 17 2021.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're on 1.7. and the models in `apps` are not properly reloaded after a change from a previous migration has affected one of them. Handling of this is better in 1.8.

A workaround is to use directly add the primary key of `Item`:

```
def categorise(apps, schema_editor):
    Category = apps.get_model("orders", "Category")
    Item = apps.get_model("orders", "Item")
    some_category = Category.objects.create(name="Category name")
    some_category.items.add(Item.objects.get(name="Item name").pk)
    # or for multiple items
    some_category.items.add(Item.objects.filter(...).values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

Comment: I am in fact on 1.8. I can confirm that using the primary key does work, but it seems quite suboptimal. I would rather rely on the correctness that the type checker provides. I have dropped the database and performed the migrations from 0001 all over again, but the situation remains.

Comment: Can you check if `id(Item)` and `id(Category.items.rel.to)` are indeed different? That would explain the behaviour. A look at the previous migrations might also help to determine whether this is a bug in your code, or in Django.

Comment: The first one presents me with an id, but that second expression triggers `AttributeError: 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'rel'`

Comment: Whoops - try `id(Category.items.field.related_model)`.

Comment: Yeah, they're indeed different. I'll edit my original question with the relevant other migrations.

Comment: I now realise that you might have been on to something when blaming 1.7, though. The first few migrations originate from when this project was built using 1.7.7. Is there a good way to update/recover from this? Or should I trash my migrations and start at `0001` again? In this scenario I don't have anyone upstream, but I'd quite like to know for future reference.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, but it doesn't hurt to try - just rename the migrations folder and see if the new migrations work. Do the migrations 0003 and 0004 change `Item` in any way? It might be related to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24573.

Comment: Migration 0003 does in fact alter a different field that I had omitted for brevity. I'll add it in. Anyway, when moving away the migrations and rebuilding them, it worked just fine. That's a bit unfortunate, as you'd hope that migrations would be robust against this sort of thing. I'll have a look and see if I can find the differences. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, I just found out that running `python manage.py migrate` twice does in fact fix the issue as well. The second time around, the `id` fields you mentioned are identical. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: I am trying the pk approach but if I pass a list as an argument to `add`, I get: `E   TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. I'm also on 1.8. Anybody has any idea of what else I could try?

Comment: @Ariel No idea, it's better to ask a new question.